# Getting Unauthenticated from react-query at POST request

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query, tanstack

I'm trying to figure out why I can't make a post request using react-query. Basically, I try to write the code below, which is working, using react-query:

//makeRequest implementation

```
import axios from "axios";

export const makeRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: false,
});

const today = moment();
  const currentMonth = today.format("MM");
  const currentYear = today.format("YYYY");
  const date = `${currentYear}-${currentMonth}`;
```

//this code is working

```
const [tours, setTours] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await makeRequest.post(
          "get-tours",
          { data: date },
          { headers }
        );
        console.log(res.data);
        setTours(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [date]);
```

//this code return 401 - Unauthorized, the response is 'Unauthenticated.' and I don't understand why

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(["tours"], () =>
    makeRequest
      .post("get-tours", {
        headers,
        data: { data: date },
      })
      .then((res) => res.data)
  );
```

Can someone, please help me? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the same params? `makeRequest.post("get-tours", {{ headers }, { data: date }})`

Comment: omg...such a stupid mistake. thank you so much @devpolo!